# WHM Root Url Change

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have opened a username under my WHM and index.php appears under 243.51.31.41/~Myusername/, how can I make the files appear on just 243.51.31.41 instead?

Answer (score 0):

put this on your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 243.51.31.41:80>

DocumentRoot /home/Myusername/

</VirtualHost>
```